# Why is "8 Simple Rules" named so?

Tags: title, 8-simple-rules

Why is the TV show, *[8 Simple Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8_Simple_Rules)* named so? I have watched the whole first season and there is no mention of any "Rule(s)" at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Its named after the book **8 Simple Rules for Dating My Teenage Daughter: And other tips from a beleaguered father (not that any of them work)** by W. Bruce Cameron.

FWIW, the rules are:

> 1: Use your hands on my daughter and you'll lose them after.
>
> 2: You make her cry, I make you cry.
>
> 3: Safe sex is a myth. Anything you try will be hazardous to your
>   health.
>
> 4: Bring her home late, there's no next date.
>
> 5: Only delivery men honk. Dates ring the doorbell. Once.
>
> 6: No complaining while you're waiting for her. If you're bored,
>   change my oil.
>
> 7: If your pants hang off your hips, I'll gladly secure them with my
>   staple gun.
>
> 8: Dates must be in crowded public place. You want romance? Read a
>   book

Comment: #5: I know it along the lines of _if you honk you better be delivering somehting, because you're sure as hell not picking anything up._

Answer (score 20):

The show is **based on a book by [W. Bruce Cameron](http://www.brucecameron.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=58&Itemid=67):**

[image: 8 simple rules]

[**The Rules are:**](http://www.brucecameron.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63:8-simple-rules-for-dating-my-teenage-daughter&catid=35&Itemid=67)

> **Rule One:**
>
> - If you pull into my driveway and honk you’d better be delivering a package, because you’re sure as heck not picking anything up.
>
> **Rule Two:**
>
> - You do not touch my daughter in front of me. You may glance at her, so long as you do not peer at anything below her neck. If you cannot keep your eyes or hands off of my daughter’s body, I will remove them.
>
> **Rule Three:**
>
> - I am aware that it is considered fashionable for boys of your age to wear their trousers so loosely that they appear to be falling off their hips. Please don’t take this as an insult, but you and all of your friends are complete idiots. Still, I want to be fair and open minded about this issue, so I propose this compromise: You may come to the door with your underwear showing and your pants ten sizes too big, and I will not object. However, In order to assure that your clothes do not, in fact, come off during the course of your date with my daughter, I will take my electric staple gun and fasten your trousers securely in place around your waist.
>
> **Rule Four:**
>
> - I’m sure you’ve been told that in today’s world, sex without utilizing a “barrier method” of some kind can kill you. Let me elaborate: when it comes to sex, I am the barrier, and I WILL kill you.
>
> **Rule Five:**
>
> - You may believe that in order for us to get to know each other, we should talk about sports, politics, and other issues of the day. Please do not do this. The only information I require from you is an indication of when you expect to have my daughter safely back at my house, and the only word I need from you on this subject is “early.”
>
> **Rule Six:**
>
> - I have no doubt you are a popular fellow, with many opportunities to date other girls. This is fine with me as long as it is okay with my daughter. Otherwise, once you have gone out with my little girl, you will continue to date no one but her until she is finished with you. If you make her cry, I will make YOU cry.
>
> **Rule Seven:**
>
> - As you stand in my front hallway, waiting for my daughter to appear, and more than an hour goes by, do not sigh and fidget. If you want to be on time for the movie, you should not be dating. My daughter is putting on her makeup, a process which can take longer than painting the Golden Gate Bridge. Instead of just standing there, why don’t you do something useful, like changing the oil in my car?
>
> **Rule Eight:**
>
> - The following places are not appropriate for a date with my daughter: Places where there are beds, sofas, or anything softer than a wooden stool. Places where parents, policemen, or nuns are not within eyesight. Places where there is darkness. Places where there is dancing, holding hands, or happiness. Places where the ambient temperature is warm enough to induce my daughter to wear shorts, tank tops, midriff T-shirts, or anything other than a goose down parka zipped up to her chin. Movies with a strong romantic or sexual theme are to be avoided; movies which feature chain saws are okay.

Comment: why is there no mention of any of the rules in the show?

Comment: @myselfpoddar - The book is, obviously, about more than just listing _8 simple rules_, it's sort of a "survival guide" for parents with teenage daughters. And as far as I remember at least some of the rules get mentioned (or acted out) in the TV show.